# How to get all list of id with specific properties in sqlalchemy async

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

Hey I am trying to learn sqlalchemy but I am stucked at getting list of all User id whose state is ON. The query does not work in async sqlalchemy.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
async def free_user():
    stmt = select(User).where(User.state =='ON')
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
        return result.first()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct code

```
async def free_user():
    stmt = select(User).where(User.state == 'ON')
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
        return [user.user_id for user in result.scalars()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all()` to [retrieve all rows in a list](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncResult.all):

```py
    ...
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
        return result.all()
```